# fetching mysql content

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very short question: How can i fetch mysql content using php and preview it like this:

```
<div>
<p>first line content</p>
<p>second line content</p>
<p>third line content</p>
</div>
<div>
<p>fourth line content</p>
<p>fifth line content</p>
<p>sixth line content</p>
</div>
//...and so on...
<div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through the results, and when the 3rd row has been entered, end a div, and start a new one.

```
$i = 0;
echo '<div>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql_result)){
    if ($i == 3){ // do this if before echo-ing a new <p> to prevent an empty div
        echo '</div><div>';
        $i = 0;
    }
    echo '<p>' . $row['content'] . '</p>';
    $i++;
}
echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$i=0;
echo '<div>';
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
  if($i==3) {
    echo '</div><div>';
    $i=0;
  }
  echo '<p>'.$row['name'].'</p>';
  $i++;
}
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Like, this is really fun, exactly same time. Even made the same guesses about functions and variable names almost. Though your solution takes up more space(s) ;)